# Программное подключение к WiFi точке

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, wifi

Замысел следующий:

1. Получить список Wi-Fi сетей.
2. Подключение к сети по паролю.
3. Получить статус подключения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот подходящее API

http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#213980

Comment: @ICE, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.